# Urbanairship SDK & Apportable

Tags: apportable

I'm now trying to port IOS game with UrbanArship SDK.
When launching `apportable load`, getting following error:

```
Airship/UI/Default/Push/Classes/Shared/UAPushMoreSettingsViewController.m:312:47: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier 'UAPushSettingsAliasViewController'
                self.aliasViewController = [[[UAPushSettingsAliasViewCon...
                                              ^
1 error generated.
```

How I can set in configuration.json file to ignore Airship folder files? If removing folder from IOS Project everything compiles.

Answer (score 1):

Add the UAirship to the "remove_params" section of configurations.json:

```
"deps": [ UAirship ],
```

If there are source files in your project you don't want to compile, add them to the sources section of remove_params:

```
"sources": [ Airship/UI/Default/Push/Classes/Shared/UAPushMoreSettingsViewController.m ],
```

Comment: Unfortionalty "deps": [ "UAirship" ] doesn't solve problem, project still not compiling if Airship folder added to project.

Comment: Thanks, Exclude sources works - tested previously, only problem that there is about 50 files and each should be added to exclusion, would be nice to have option exclude folder. How understood from configuration.js comments there is option to use regex to exclude files, but currently with no sucess. Tried something like UA[.*]